# function to determine if a number is in the fibonacci or not in sml?

Tags: sml

I need to write a function in sml that takes a number and determines if it is or not a fibonacci number. 
I have already done the fibonacci func

```
fun fib 1=0
  | fib 2=1
  | fib n= fib (n-1)+fib(n-2);
```

but i cannot figure out first one? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Write a function that generates the fibonacci sequence up to that number. If the last number generated is the number itself, then it is a fibonacci number. Send us your code.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out.

```
fun isfib 0 = true
  | isfib x =
    let
      fun help (i,j) = if j >= x then x = j else help (j,j+i)
    in
      help (0,1)
    end
```

I created a helper function that forward generates the sequence until i see a number greater than or equal to the number i am interested in.  Then I test to see if that fibonacci number is equal to x.